# Firebase Error(Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, firebase

I try to make the Firebase authentication work I added the different dependencies in the gradle file but when I launch the app I get an error:http://prntscr.com/ik0xcc
http://prntscr.com/ik0y2h

Here are my dependencies: http://prntscr.com/ik0xrs

Comment: try to clean and rebuild the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your build dependencies to use:

```
com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:3.2.1
```

That is the version [compatible with Firebase SDK 11.8.0](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#dependencies).